# How are swaption expiries scheduled if given with tenor?

Tags: swaption, scheduling

Today I came across a trade which was a "1m5y" swaption booked as of trade date Tuesday 28th Feb 2023.

This swaption has an expiry date of Thursday 30th March 2023. How was this expiry date determined from the definition of a "1m5y"?

If a non-end-of-month parameter is used (given 28th Feb 2023 is end of month) the expiry date should be determined under regular scheduling as Tuesday 28th March 2023.

If an end-of-month parameter is used then the expiry date should be scheduled as Friday 31st March 2023.

None of these days are holidays. Is there some convention I am unaware of in swaptions I cannot understand what logical rule would result in 30th March 2023?

Comment: Isn't this just normal T+2, as in effective date is T+2, and add 1m.

Comment: T+2 convention is the swap effective date, so expiry should be 28th March 2023 and swap effective date 30th March 2023 for a 1m5y swaption traded on 28th Feb 2023 (using nonEOM). So this does not address the issue raised in the question.

Comment: Under standard conventions you are right.  So there must have been something specific going on with that trade.

Comment: @dm63 thx for confirming, I was coming round to that conclusion also.